# jQuery for loop not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I am working on a plugin and currently want to provide dynamic behavior to my isotope gallery. The issue is weird as code is all fine but does not work. It works for one last gallery only while I want to make every gallery working fine.

The scenario is like, there can be multiple galleries on same page and I am just adding a digit to each gallery to assign that a unique id and then I can update my jquery as well.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
var count = jQuery('div[filter-id="filter-count"]').length;
alert(count);
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    alert(i);
    if (jQuery('#gallery-listed' +i+ '').length) {
            var $container = jQuery('#gallery-listed' +i+ '');
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: '*',
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false
                    }
                });
            });
            jQuery('#filterlist_v5' +i+ ' a').click(function() {
                jQuery('#filterlist_v5' +i+ ' .current').removeClass('current');
                jQuery(this).addClass('current');

                var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
}
```

I am getting count of my data attr to make sure how many galleries are there, and then looping that as well. Html code looks fine and same is for jquery while I feel that jquery is not printing that code as it shows same code in my script once I check by footer scripts. Hope I am able to make you understand my problem.

Comment: It would help if you provided your html as well as indicate what browser console or alert shows when you run the above.

Comment: ok let me add my html as well

Comment: html is same as jquery code ... it alerts every thing fine as well ... but once I click on filter button of first gallery it shuffles filters of last gallery while I want it to work at its own :(

Comment: that code works fine in my php file ... but I want to make that working from my scripts file because that's more professional approach ... but what's the issue from scripts folder while its working in php file ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you can add a class to your code and can use each function of jQuery like shown below:

Note: let suppose your class name is "testing" then code will look like shown below:

```
$(".testing").each(function(){
var i = 0;
if (jQuery('#gallery-listed' +i+ '').length) {
        var $container = jQuery('#gallery-listed' +i+ '');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.isotope({
                filter: '*',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
            });
        });
        jQuery('#filterlist_v5' +i+ ' a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#filterlist_v5' +i+ ' .current').removeClass('current');
            jQuery(this).addClass('current');

            var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    } 
i = i + 1;
});
```

Hope it works fine for you by now: Just concentrate on these two line below:

```
var i = 0;
```

and

```
i = i +1;
```

which sets i to 0 and increments is value with 1 after each iteration. And so this will run let suppose if you have 5 classes of testing then 5 times and you will get your results.

Comment: yes I got your point and I am using same technique now, its working fine at mine end ... thanks a lot for your time